# Cannot connect to local server using Arduino Wifi-Shiled

Tags: c, arduino

I am trying to upload data from arduino to a local server using Arduino wifi shied.But the code never reaches the line "connected".I am using WAMP server.The IP address ping of the arduino wifi shield is okay.The wifi shield connects to the network.The code is below:

```
 #include <TinkerKit.h>
   #include <WiFi.h>
   #include <SPI.h>

    char ssid[] = "Connectify-moloi"; // your network SSID (name)
    char pass[] = "1234567890"; // your network password
    int status = WL_IDLE_STATUS;

    //WiFiServer server(80);
    long previousMillis = 0;
    unsigned long currentMillis = 0;
    long interval = 250000; // READING INTERVAL
    int sensor;
    int analog_val;

    String data;
    String Hall;
    String Temp;
    WiFiClient client;
    IPAddress server(192,168,164,101);
    void setup() { 
    Serial.begin(9600);

     while ( status != WL_CONNECTED) {
    Serial.print("Attempting to connect to SSID: ");
    Serial.println(ssid);
    status = WiFi.begin(ssid, pass);
    // wait 10 seconds for connection:
    delay(10000);
    }

    // you're connected now, so print out the status:
    printWifiStatus();


              Hall = "50";
              Temp = "50";

        data = "";
    }

    void loop(){

        currentMillis = millis();
        if(currentMillis - previousMillis > interval) { // READ ONLY ONCE PER INTERVAL
            previousMillis = currentMillis;
                     Hall ="50"; //String(analog_val);
                     Temp ="50"; //String(sensor);

        }

        data = "temp1=" + Hall + "&hum1=" + Temp;
           client.flush();
        if (client.connect(server,80)) { // REPLACE WITH YOUR SERVER ADDRESS
            Serial.println("Connected");
            client.println("POST project/add.php HTTP/1.1"); 
            client.println("Host: 192.168.164.101"); // SERVER ADDRESS HERE TOO
            client.println("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"); 
            client.print("Content-Length: "); 
            client.println(data.length()); 
            client.println(); 
            client.print(data); 
        } 

        if (client.connected()) { 
            client.stop();  // DISCONNECT FROM THE SERVER
            client.flush();
        }

        delay(7000); // WAIT FIVE MINUTES BEFORE SENDING AGAIN
    }

    void printWifiStatus() {
    // print the SSID of the network you're attached to:
    Serial.print("SSID: ");
    Serial.println(WiFi.SSID());
    // print your WiFi shield's IP address:
    IPAddress ip = WiFi.localIP();
    Serial.print("IP Address: ");
    Serial.println(ip);
    // print the received signal strength:
    long rssi = WiFi.RSSI();
    Serial.print("signal strength (RSSI):");
    Serial.print(rssi);
    Serial.println(" dBm");
    }
```

Comment: Iam using version 1.02

Comment: Assuming the credentials you pass are correct, according to ***[this](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/WiFiBegin)***, you should be connecting.  I see no issues in that part of your code.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a `POST` command, try using a `GET` request.

Change `POST project/add.php` to `GET /project/add.php?`